# Mingw32-Make & cmake 3.0

Tags: c++, opencv, makefile

Well i am trying to compile opencv on my own for eclipsecdt4. I am following a tutorial for codeblocks over here
http://kevinhughes.ca/tutorials/opencv-install-on-windows-with-codeblocks-and-mingw/

I did the cmake thing with eclipse cdt4-mingw32makefile config(tried with just mingw32 makefile too) but the makefile isnt generating. When i do mingw32-make in the build directory it says 
F:\ocv\build>mingw32-make
mingw32-make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Here is a screenshot of the build directory

[image: Screen]

Comment: What happened when you ran the cmake step?

Answer (score -1):

I had excatly the same problem....I solved it today...I forgot to press Generate in Cmake.....